# Codeigniter Ajax Call 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with ajax call in codeigniter. This is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: MY_CONSTANT + "login/autentificare",
    data: {
        login_email: login_email,
        login_password: login_password
    },
    success: function(result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result);
        if (result.errors) {
            if (result.errors.length > 0) {
                swal.fire({
                    text: result.errors,
                    icon: "error",
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
                    }
                }).then(function() {
                    KTUtil.scrollTop();
                });
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

And controller function is:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login/login');   
    }
    
    public function autentificare() {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

Every time I got 404 error for Ajax call and the url is correct.
Can you help me please?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you remove index.php from url or not?

Comment: Yes. $config['index_page'] = ''; . I tried now with index_php and work. How I can remove index.php form URL? Thank you!!

Comment: i have add answer please check.

Comment: in your config.php, is `$config['csrf_protection']`set to `true` or `false`?

Comment: It`s false csrf_protection. I tried put true and I got 403 error.

Comment: we also don't know what `MY_CONSTANT ` contains, normally I use a relative path like `url: "/login/autentificare",`

Comment: first check what you get by `alert(MY_CONSTANT);` I  think the problem is with base url.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in **.htaccess** file and put the file with in application folder location.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make a new .**htaccess** file and put inside **application** folder and add code to the file given below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for reponse, but not working. Same 404 error. Previous htaccess was: <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

Comment: I got same error. Are you sure it is a htaccess problem? Thank you!!

Comment: where you have put your .htaccess file

Comment: In application folder is the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes because you are not returning JSON data, in your controller's function

```
public function autentificare() {
        return json_encode(['response'=>'success']);
 }
```

I think this will work :)

Comment: the 404 is thrown before it gets to autentificare(), otherwise there wouldn't be a 404. And btw do not return, but echo json_encode()